# Android multiple packages in one project, what is R and how to import it?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a launcher for people with bad eyesight and a simple music player, this is my second APP so bear in mind I'm a complete noob in android and eclipse.

I tried to merge both my launcher and music player. I added the activity to the manifiest with a different intent, copied layouts and drawables to the launcher project and I added the player's package inside my /src folder.

Afterwards on the first lines of com.easyplayer.java I got this error:

```
import com.easyplayer.R;   // the import com.easyplayer.R cannot be resolved
```

This is the only bug I'm getting so I suppose I did everything else fine. I imagine R must reference the player's layout, but I'm not sure how to fix it (cleaning/rebuilding doesn't work). What is the R class? And what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `R` class you see is auto-generated by Android.  It is a utility class that contains references to all the resources in your project.  There is a few answers detailing its contents [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953077/android-what-is-r-why-is-it-so-cryptic).

You mentioned you performed a clean of your project, but you need to do a full build as well to regenerate this file.

edit: The import of the new code may have somehow invalidated your xml files.  Check to see if there are any errors there, which could be preventing the `R` file from being re-created during a build.

Comment: project > clean > clean all projects > (x) start a build automactically > accept. ? that's what I am doing.
I tried android tools > fix project properties. How do I regenerate the file?

Comment: the only error (found by eclipse) is inside /src/com.easyplayer/mainactivity.java on the line mentioned, there are others afterwards on the same file that steam from this one

Comment: What happens when you remove the import?

Answer (score 1):

if you have several packages like, **com.example.app.package1** and **com.example.app.package2**, then import the R.java file like,

**import com.example.app.R;**

And if you already have **import android.R;** then please delete that and save the file and clean the project, problem will be solve...:)