# Meaning of R.layout.activity_main in android development (JAVA language)

Tags: java, android

What is the meaning of R.layout.activity_main ?

I understand that "." operator is used to define variables of a particular object but in this case its been used twice so I can't make anything out of it. Also what exactly is "R" and "layout"?

I mean obviously they are classes (right?) but what is their function ? Basically explain R.layout.activity_main !

Please comment if question too vague or too broad.

Comment: Related posts - [Android: What is R? Why is it so Cryptic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4953077/465053) & [Understand the R class in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6804053/465053)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`R.java` is a class (with inner classes, like `layout` or `string`) generated during the build process with references to your app's resources. Every resource you create (or which is provided by Android) is referenced by an integer in `R`, called a resource id.

`R.layout.*` references any layout resource you have created, usually in `/res/layout`. So if you created an activity layout called `activity_main.xml`, you can then use the reference in `R.layout.activity_main` to access it. Many built-in functionality readily accepts such a resource id, for example [`setContentView(int layoutResid)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)) which you use during the creation of your activity and where you probably encountered this particular example.

If you create a string resource (in strings.xml) like this:

```
<string name="app_name">Application name</string>
```

it will get a new reference in `R.string.app_name`. You can then use this everywhere where a string resource is accepted, for example the `android:label` for your application in `AndroidManifest.xml`, or on a TextView; either in the xml:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    />
```

or in code: `textview.setText(R.string.app_name)`.

You can access resources programmatically using the [`Resources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) class, to which you can get a reference by calling [`getResources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) on any context (like your activity). So for example you can get your app name described above in your activity by calling `this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)`.

You can also supply different resources for different device properties/settings (like screen size or language), which you can access using the same references in `R`. The easiest example here, imho, is strings: if you add a new `values` folder in `/res` with a language specifier (so `/res/values-nl` for Dutch) and you add strings with the same identifier but a different translation and the resource management system cleverly figures out which one to provide for you based on your user's device.

I hope this helps a bit. For more information on resources see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/overview.html).

Answer (score 3):

`R` is an auto-generated class, and describe the resources of your project. It contains static inner classes. `layout` is one of them. R.layout refers to the inner class called layout. `activity_main` is a `public static final` member of the class `layout`

Answer (score 3):

In Android `R` is an Java-class that is auto-generated from your resources by the build process.

The `R.layout` member is a auto-generated class that contains all IDs for layouts.

`R.layout.activity_main` is a `static final int` member that represents the ID of the layout-file in `layout/activity_main.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so R is a generated class. If you're lucky enough you'll never see it nor have to touch it, otherwise you did something very wrong.

When you make a layout, or any change to a layout, Android Studio generates quite a couple files for you. This includes a R.java file. Here's a piece of an R.java class:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class anim {
        public static final int abc_fade_in = 0x7f050000;
        public static final int abc_fade_out = 0x7f050001;
        public static final int abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom = 0x7f050002;
        public static final int abc_popup_enter = 0x7f050003;
        public static final int abc_popup_exit = 0x7f050004;
        public static final int abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom = 0x7f050005;
        public static final int abc_slide_in_bottom = 0x7f050006;
        public static final int abc_slide_in_top = 0x7f050007;
        public static final int abc_slide_out_bottom = 0x7f050008;
        public static final int abc_slide_out_top = 0x7f050009;
    }
    public static final class attr {
        public static final int actionBarDivider = 0x7f010062;
        public static final int actionBarItemBackground = 0x7f010063;
        public static final int actionBarPopupTheme = 0x7f01005c;
        public static final int actionBarSize = 0x7f010061;
        public static final int actionBarSplitStyle = 0x7f01005e;
        public static final int actionBarStyle = 0x7f01005d;
        public static final int actionBarTabBarStyle = 0x7f010058;
        public static final int actionBarTabStyle = 0x7f010057;
        public static final int actionBarTabTextStyle = 0x7f010059;
```

As you can see, in this case if I'd type

```
R.anim.abc_fade_in
```

I'd be selecting the value 0x7f050000;.
Every layout file is mapped out in this R file, and gets an ID by which android recognizes it. The layouts are located in R.Layout. So, R.layout.activity_main gets you the value of variable activity_main of the class layout of the class R.

And again, don't try finding or changing your generated R file. Things can go very wrong if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/4953282/1393766

> R is a class containing the definitions for all resources of a particular application package. It is in the namespace of the application package.

If you want to inflate a layout inside your activity class,you can use R.layout.activity_main where layout specifies that your resource is a layout and it's name is activity_main.

If you want to use a drawable image in a layout inside your activity class,you can use R.drawable.image_name where drawable specifies that your resource is a drawable image.

Also,R.java class is an autogenerated class which is not supposed to alter manually.