# What sould I add for the last line of my code '(this,R.layout.device_name)'?

Tags: javascript, android, layout

At the last line of my below code I would like to understand the function `(this, R.layout.device_name)` as device_name layout doesn't exist on my code. I also would like to know where I can define it.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //BTAdapter
    BTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    //SwitchBT
    Switch switch_OnOff = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switchbt);
    switch_OnOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    //ListView / ArrayAdapter
    pairedDevicesAdapter = newArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.device_name)
```

Comment: That is layout file and that needs to be in layout folder, but this is basic development so I advise going through some tutorials of android.

Comment: If I add this file to my layout folder, what should be in there ? Also would you recommend any tutorials ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/courses

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of R.layout.activity\_main in android development (JAVA language)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649447/meaning-of-r-layout-activity-main-in-android-development-java-language)

Comment: Yes thank you ! My problem is solved I just had to create a new layout file called 'device_name' - right click on 'res/layout' and my code appeared as correct. However, I don't really see the use of this class as it only contains a TextView...

Comment: Post your solution based from comments as answer to close this open-standing question.