# Cannot change UI in runOnUiThread

Tags: android, user-interface, android-runonuithread

I want change TextView  content to the result of calculation in thread, but crashing when execution. Here's my code.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (i < 5) {
               i++;
            }
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    TextView txv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txvone);
                    Log.d("123","i = "+ i);
                    txv.setText(i);//CRASH!!!
                }
            });
        }
}).start();
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `String` type to the `setText()` method. When you pass an integer type, it performs a lookup to the `R`([see : R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953077/android-what-is-r-why-is-it-so-cryptic)) file for a string resource with the specified ID. Since the ID does not match any item in your `strings.xml` file, the exception thrown is `ResourceNotFoundException`.

Like Sree said, try the code below, it is guaranteed to work.

```
txv.setText(String.valueOf(i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) it says `setText(int resid)`.

So, the int valu, you pass for this method should be a resource id (one from the `R.string` static member). It's a bit annoying, but I think, Android Studio warns you about the `@ResourceId` annotation on the prameter.

If you'd like to set the text to 5, you should do the `String.valueOf(5)` method call, as suggested in the comments.