# error: ';' expected & Error: Execution failed for task ':android:compileDebugJava'. > Compilation failed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, android-fragments

getting error: ';' expected & Error: Execution failed for task ':android:compileDebugJava'. > Compilation failed

I know that the ";" is missing right here

```
import com.doragames.adventure.android.R
```

but when I add it I got other errors like

```
Error:(181, 39) error: cannot find symbol variable leaderboard_high_scores
Error:(191, 39) error: cannot find symbol variable leaderboard_high_scores
Error:(238, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable achievement_getting_started
Error:(243, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable achievement_like_a_rover
Error:(248, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable achievement_spirit
Error:(253, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable achievement_curiosity
Error:(258, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable achievement_5k_club
Error:(263, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable achievement_10k_club
Error:(268, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable achievement_25k_club
Error:(273, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable achievement_50k_club
Error:(278, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable achievement_10_jump_street
Error:(283, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable achievement_100_jump_street
Error:(288, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable achievement_500_jump_street
Error:(292, 34) error: cannot find symbol variable ad_unit_id
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:compileDebugJava'.
```

this is my androidLauncher.java

```
package com.doragames.adventure.android;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.doragames.adventure.MartianRun;
import com.doragames.adventure.utils.Constants;
import com.doragames.adventure.utils.GameEventListener;
import com.doragames.adventure.utils.GameManager;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.games.basegameutils.GameHelper;
import com.doragames.adventure.android.R


public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements GameHelper.GameHelperListener,
    GameEventListener {

private static String SAVED_LEADERBOARD_REQUESTED = "SAVED_LEADERBOARD_REQUESTED";
private static String SAVED_ACHIEVEMENTS_REQUESTED = "SAVED_ACHIEVEMENTS_REQUESTED";

private GameHelper gameHelper;

private AdView mAdView;
private boolean mLeaderboardRequested;
private boolean mAchievementsRequested;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the layout
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

    // Game view
    View gameView = initializeForView(new MartianRun(this), config);
    layout.addView(gameView);


    mAdView = createAdView();
    mAdView.loadAd(createAdRequest());

    layout.addView(mAdView, getAdParams());

    setContentView(layout);

    gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
    gameHelper.setup(this);
    gameHelper.setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    gameHelper.onStart(this);
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    gameHelper.onStop();
    GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    gameHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(SAVED_LEADERBOARD_REQUESTED, mLeaderboardRequested);
    outState.putBoolean(SAVED_ACHIEVEMENTS_REQUESTED, mAchievementsRequested);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mLeaderboardRequested = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_LEADERBOARD_REQUESTED, false);
    mAchievementsRequested = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVED_ACHIEVEMENTS_REQUESTED, false);
}

private AdRequest createAdRequest() {
    return new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
}

private AdView createAdView() {
    AdView adView = new AdView(this);

    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(getAdMobUnitId());

    return adView;
}

private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams getAdParams() {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    return adParams;
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
    // handle sign-in failure (e.g. show Sign In button)
    mLeaderboardRequested = false;
    mAchievementsRequested = false;
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    // handle sign-in success
    if (GameManager.getInstance().hasSavedMaxScore()) {
        GameManager.getInstance().submitSavedMaxScore();
    }

    if (mLeaderboardRequested) {
        displayLeaderboard();
        mLeaderboardRequested = false;
    }

    if (mAchievementsRequested) {
        displayAchievements();
        mAchievementsRequested = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void displayAd() {
    mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void hideAd() {
    mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
public void submitScore(int score) {
    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_scores), score);
    } else {
        GameManager.getInstance().saveScore(score);
    }
}

@Override
public void displayLeaderboard() {
    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient(),
                getString(R.string.leaderboard_high_scores)), 24);
    } else {
        gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
        mLeaderboardRequested = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void displayAchievements() {
    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(
                Games.Achievements.getAchievementsIntent(gameHelper.getApiClient()), 25);
    } else {
        gameHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
        mAchievementsRequested = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void share() {
    String url = String.format("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=%s",
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
    String message = String.format(Constants.SHARE_MESSAGE_PREFIX, url);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, Constants.SHARE_TITLE));
}

@Override
public void unlockAchievement(String id) {
    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        Games.Achievements.unlock(gameHelper.getApiClient(), id);
        GameManager.getInstance().setAchievementUnlocked(id);
    }
}

@Override
public void incrementAchievement(String id, int steps) {
    if (gameHelper.isSignedIn()) {
        Games.Achievements.increment(gameHelper.getApiClient(), id, steps);
        GameManager.getInstance().incrementAchievementCount(id, steps);
    }
}

@Override
public String getGettingStartedAchievementId() {
    return getString(R.string.achievement_getting_started);
}

@Override
public String getLikeARoverAchievementId() {
    return getString(R.string.achievement_like_a_rover);
}

@Override
public String getSpiritAchievementId() {
    return getString(R.string.achievement_spirit);
}

@Override
public String getCuriosityAchievementId() {
    return getString(R.string.achievement_curiosity);
}

@Override
public String get5kClubAchievementId() {
    return getString(R.string.achievement_5k_club);
}

@Override
public String get10kClubAchievementId() {
    return getString(R.string.achievement_10k_club);
}

@Override
public String get25kClubAchievementId() {
    return getString(R.string.achievement_25k_club);
}

@Override
public String get50kClubAchievementId() {
    return getString(R.string.achievement_50k_club);
}

@Override
public String get10JumpStreetAchievementId() {
    return getString(R.string.achievement_10_jump_street);
}

@Override
public String get100JumpStreetAchievementId() {
    return getString(R.string.achievement_100_jump_street);
}

@Override
public String get500JumpStreetAchievementId() {
    return getString(R.string.achievement_500_jump_street);
}

private String getAdMobUnitId() {
    return getString(R.string.ad_unit_id);
}

}
```

Comment: Adding the `;` is definitely correct, the errors you recieve after adding it have been there already but just weren't shown because the syntax checker stopped at the first occurrence of the missing semicolon (not sure if this is exactly right, but I think it's at least a pointer). The error messages say that all your variables of `R.string` (e.g. `R.string.leaderboard_high_scores`) aren't defined.

Comment: and what's the solution with R.string error plz

Comment: Sorry, @houd-bl, I don't have very much knowledge on Android programming. I would try searching for probelms with the `R` class specifically. Have you had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804053/understand-the-r-class-in-android) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953077/android-what-is-r-why-is-it-so-cryptic)?

Comment: Thank you anyway @TuringTux

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error the first time prevented R from properly generating. Rebuild the project and make sure the `;` is there and the class will be generated and it should work again.

Answer (score 0):

Clean project and the rebuild it