# android studio java package r does not exist

Tags: android

Hello im new to android studio and to java so i tried to create button that redirects from login to register page, but i keep getting these errors even thought i did everything correctly following the tutorial

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.register);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openregister();
        }
    });

}
public void openregister (){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,register.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}
error i get in lines package R does not exist
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
button = findViewById(R.id.register);
```

and cannot find symbol class register in

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,register.class);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the class R in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953077/what-is-the-class-r-in-android)

Comment: import your app's R file. ```import your.package.name.R;```

Comment: Also, read Rishabh's link for more understanding of R.

Comment: you can try cleaning your project