# How to control the RELATIVE path of a reference Library Project?

Tags: android, adt, android-lvl, library-project

I am trying to add the LVL library project to my application's project. It should be simple and straightforward, but it isn't:

When I click the `Add...` button, I receive the Library Project Selection dialog as expected:

[image: Library Project Selection dialog]

I select it and it is being accepted with the green checkmark next to it.

However, when I re-open that Properties > Android box again, it gets a red X next to it, making it unusable:

[image: My application trying to reference LVL]

There is an excellent answer documenting the "delicate behavior" of referencing a library project, but despite implementing the tips there (same root directory), I am still having this problem.

How do I solve (or workaround) this problem?

Is there a way to make Eclipse/ADT use fewer`..\..`s to represent the path of the referenced library project? (all is needed to reference that library correctly is `..\..\thisisinsane\library`, there really is no need for all that `..\..\..\..\..\..`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by following the excellent steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928784/how-to-duplicate-an-sdk-sample-project-into-workspace).

In essence, The Eclipse+ADT duo doesn't "like" projects that aren't in the workspace, regardless whether these are application projects or library projects (even if Google created them).