# Unable to import android projects and solution for .classpath, .project not found

Tags: android

Hey guys I am sharing the two solutions to the scenarios for importing android projects into workspace these solved my problems

Problem A: How to import project android projects- steps to follow

Problem B: What if the downloaded or the target android program doesn't have the .classpath and .project files in it.

Answer (score 1):

A.1. First and foremost to import any project into eclipse, follow the instructions
Right Click on workspace->New->other->select "Android code from existing project" under android , then locate the project and import to workspace(chech mark the "copy projects to workspace").

Some times after locating the project you may not be able to select "OK" thats because may be .classpath and .project files are missing fomm your project so to clear that you have to do this: go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8351270/3228960) or see below

B.1. Copy ".classpath" and ".project" files from other android project and, paste to to your project directory or create a new project

B.2. Open the ".project" file in notepad and replace the name with the name of the project you want to import.(If you don't know the name the check it in the string.xml in the values folder(inside res folder))