# Add Library(not a jar) in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

Hy!

I read this http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html but when i press add library the downloaded libary doesn't occur.

How to solve that?
Where do i have to put the files?

Library + info :https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/README.md

Buildtarget: 2.1 API 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the downloaded library as a project to your workspace (in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928784/how-to-duplicate-an-sdk-sample-project-into-workspace/4960822#4960822) I provided below, there is a very helpful tip as to how to resolve target versions discrepancies).

Then, you have to mark your library as a library via Properties > Android > `Is Library` checkmark.

Comment: mhm i want to take the library from https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @test123123 That's fine. You still have to make sure that this `Is Library` checkbox is checked (for the library you downloaded and added to your workspace).

Comment: how do i add the library to eclipes? when i press import and select the downloaded folder no project occurs

Comment: @test123123 Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928784/how-to-duplicate-an-sdk-sample-project-into-workspace/4960822#4960822

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have two or more projects in your Eclipse workspace.  One of them is going to be your main project and at least one is going to be your library project.

It's very simple :

1. Make sure your library project is marked as a library project in the properties -> android section.
2. In your main project go to the properties -> android section of the project and add your library project.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more details? Screenshots may be useful as well. I don't know the steps you're taking, or even what you're trying to accomplish.

Libraries generally refer to what version of Android you're using--as opposed to adding a third-party JAR to provide specific functionality in your project.

If you are trying to change the Android build target (using 2.3, Gingerbread, instead of 2.2, Froyo, for example) then right-click the project in Project Explorer, click "Properties," then go to the "Android" section, select one of the checkboxes and click OK.

If you want to change a different library, follow the steps above, but instead of going to the "Android" section of the project properties window, go to "Java Build Path" and click "Add Library." If that isn't enough information for you, please state why you are trying to change the library, and what exact steps you are taking and what the result is.